# How to parse values from a hashmap to a variable

Tags: java, class, hashmap

So I'm trying to create a class which only stores a hashmap and it's values as I will need to access them from another class at some point and it's values could change at any point. Below is an example of what I'm trying

**PriceInfo.java**

```
public class PriceInfo {
   public static HashMap PriceInformation() {
       HashMap<String, Double> trainerPrice = new HashMap<>();
       trainerPrice.put("Nike", 199.99);
       trainerPrice.put("Adidas", 150.99);
       return trainerPrice;
   }
}
```

**DiscountChecker.java**

```
public class DiscountChecker {
    public boolean AllowDiscount(String discountCode, String tBrand) {
        if (discountCode.equals("Hello")) {
            double tPrice = PriceInfo.PriceInformation().get(tBrand);
            double discountedPrice = 0.8 * tPrice;
            return true;
        } else {    
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, I keep getting an error saying incompatible types and double is required.

The error is on this line double tPrice = PriceInfo.PriceInformation().get(tBrand);

Comment: Take care of Java naming cnvention. method names should start with lower case character

Comment: Your `PriceInformation` declares to return `double`, but tries to return the map.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Doesn't it tell you exactly the line number where the problem is? If you haven't already, install an IDE like Eclipse and it will tell you what the problem is and even suggest an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change the signature of your method from

```
public static double PriceInformation ()
```

to

```
public static Map<String, Double> PriceInformation ()
```

*Aside*: Please follow proper naming conventions and change your method names to start with lowercase.

Comment: Hi sorry I edited it as I sent it and forgot to change that back -_-. Thank you though. It's currently set to public static hashmap but still the same error

Comment: @Jay same error here means what? can you update the question with error that you get after making the above change?

Comment: Done. Sorry, I'm having such a mare today

Comment: @Jay Same suggestion again. Just notice the signature I've shared. `Map<String, Double>`

Comment: That worked, it's now returning the value. Thank you

Comment: @Jay Good. Don't forget to accept an answer if that helps :)

Comment: Yeah, I completely forgot, I panicked a bit after seeing the errors in my initial before editing it. But thanks for your time :)